# Java 1.1.8 game JKobo stopped working with Java 1.8.0_251 (NullPointerException)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

The Java game JKobo (still) works with Java 1.1.8, but when I give this a try with Windows 7's Java 1.8.0_251 it produces an error:

```
C:\PROGRA~1\Test>java -cp c:\progra~1\test JKobo
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.Locale.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Locale.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at Kobo.<init>(Kobo.java)
        at JKobo.main(JKobo.java)
```

The shoot 'em up-package, including *.java source files (in the file JKoboSrc.zip) of the XKobo clone is available here: https://hobbes.nmsu.edu/download/pub/java/games/action/jkobo100.zip

I've read what this could be about, but I couldn't understand that. I'm not an OO programmer, nor do I know if this can work with both Java 1.1.8 and Java 1.8.0_251, nor am I aware of programming language changes since Java 1.1.8.

Is this an easy fix? If so, how? I've found an extra package with a JAVAC.EXE, but I have no clue what to change in the *.java file(s). Presumably it should be an easy fix.

Comment: Are you telling me there is something that still runs Java 1.1.8? The ancient version from 1997?

Comment: Yes, it's not a typo. Even applets still work. Perhaps don't blame 1997, but e.g. PDF is as Portable as Adobe wants it to be. So some people still have to deal with Acrobat Reader 4, just because Adobe cannot be bothered to produce readers for all OSes in quite active use. Neverteheless I hope nothing but a Java standard was changed, so this game can work with both/all Java's. Including 1.8.0.